# String editing function

Tags: string, replace, vbscript

I have a situation in which I call a function that takes one parameter (a string).  For some reason, my code will not accept the string variable I give it, and gives me an error.  Am I making some stupid syntax error? Here is the much simplified code skeleton:

```
Dim input, message, done, testFormatMessage
Do
    good = 0
    input = InputBox("Type the name:", "Name prompt-- By JM", "Type name/command here...")
    message = UCase(input)
    'if you hit cancel or close the window:
    If message = "" Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    'if the input contains a '%' then format the input to delete that symbol
    If InStr(message, "%") > 0 Then
        testFormatMessage = Format(message)
        MsgBox(testFormatMessage)
    End If
    If input = "Type name/command here..." Then
        MsgBox("You didn't type a name/command")
        done - 1
    End If
    If done = 0 Then
        MsgBox("'" & input & "' is not a recognized name/command.")
    End If
Loop

Function Format(m)
    m = m.Replace("%", "")
    Format = m
End Function
```

This will work fine until your input contains a '%'.  If it does, the program crashes, resulting in an error that states

**Line: *TheFirstLineOfTheFunctionNamedFormatInTheScript***

**Error: Object Required 'm'**

Why can my function not accept the string 'message' as a parameter to replace the object 'm' when it runs?  I admit I am around intermediate level for VBScript programming, so don't be harsh if I've made a silly syntax error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because a string is not an object in VBScript, so it has no `.Replace` method. Use VBScript functions for string manipulation instead (as you have using `InStr` and `UCase`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I discovered my answer thanks to @KenWhite.  As Ken stated, a string is not an object in VBScript, therefore it has no .Replace method.  Here is a sample replace method that will actually work!

```
Function Replace(case, replaceCaseWithThis, str)
    Dim obj

    Set obj = new RegExp
    obj.Pattern = pattern
    obj.IgnoreCase = True

    Replace = obj.Replace(str, replaceCaseWithThis)
End Function
```

Now, an example of calling the method with example output.

```
Dim startingString, resultingString
startingString = "I am a string for testing purposes"
resultingString = Replace("string", "series of characters", startingString)
MsgBox(resultingString)
```

This will show a message box with the following written in it:

**I am a series of characters for testing purposes**

Once again thanks to @KenWhite for seeing my silly mistake, this answer is being posted so that this may be used as a reference source.

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

Thanks to @Tomalak, I also see that I was following the VBScript *method* for Replacing, rather than the *function*.  Using the *function*, the code simplifies to:

```
Replace(m, "%", "")
```

Thanks again @Tomalak

Comment: VBScript has a built-in `Replace()` function. Why not use it?

Comment: @Tomalak, this was my original dilemma.  I attempted to use the built-in Replace() function to alter a string, however it will not work when altering strings as such. rather you must alter objects. Therefore, in the answer I provided as a reference, I created the object 'obj' and used that to successfully alter the string.

Comment: Your original attempt `m.Replace("%", "")` should read `Replace(m, "%", "")`. I don't see why that would not work. See [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now.  This is my fault, I was following the rules of the Replace() method, and you were following the Replace() function.  They are quite different in VBScript, as it turns out.  Unfortunately, I come from Java (many years of experience) and so seeing the words 'method' and seeing how it was 'object.Replace()' seemed completely correct.  So basically, yes you are correct I can actually just write a line stating `Replace(m, "%", "")`.  This is simply just a form of command I am not used to doing (as much as I should be).  Thanks for the help

Comment: I hope you'll notice I have updated the answer provided to accommodate your input, as well as a direct citation to you.

Comment: Exactly. VBScript's primitive types do not have methods, as they are not objects - just like in Java, if there were no auto-boxing. There is a set of functions that operate on primitive types, e.g. `Replace`, `Trim` or `InStr`, but you still have to pass the subject as a parameter.

Comment: (You might want to put that edit on top, as your approach using regular expressions really isn't the ideal way to solve this.)

Comment: FWIW, your code should probably look something like this: http://pastebin.com/nZNdgjDA